# How exactly does int position gets pass into a fragment adapter?

Tags: java, android

I am very confuse about the following code

```
   public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

My concern is that where does the what passes in the int position argument for the adapter to be able to pass to use it. This concern also extends to the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) code where I am not so sure what exactly pass in the bundle for the activity.

Comment: You don't need to pass anything to onCreate, but it would come from either the intent that called that activity or an overridden method `onSaveInstanceState`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its called by the FragmentPageAdapter method instantiateItem

[FragmentPageAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)